# TYPO3 How to add Create new button on TCA?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid

I would like to build a slider (Own Content Element). So on the backend i would like to have a section with multiple records. What do i mean? By clicking the "Create new" i would like to have an image selection and rich text selection.

Something like that.

[image: Section]

How can i achieve this?

So far i have:

**TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php**

which gives me the rich editor and the image selection in backend, but not grouped.

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['my_slider'] = array(   'showitem' => '   
    --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.headers;headers,bodytext,assets;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.media, 
   ',    
    'columnsOverrides' => [
          'bodytext' => [
             'config' => [
                'enableRichtext' => true,
                'richtextConfiguration' => 'default'
             ]
         ]  
      ]
    );
```

**tt_content.typosript**

```
tt_content {
 my_slider < lib.contentElement
 my_slider {
  templateRootPaths.10 = {$Private}Templates/
  templateName = Slider.html
  dataProcessing {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    10 {
      references.fieldName = assets
      as = images
    }
  }
}
}
```

**Slider.html**

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

  <h1>{data.header}</h1>
  <p>{data.bodytext}</p>
   <f:for each="{images}" as="image">
     <f:image image="{image}" alt="{file.properties.alt}" cropVariant="desktop"/>
      {image.description}
  </f:for>
   <f:debug>{data}</f:debug>
</html>
```

Now with the current code i get the results in frontend. One Text and one Image. But how can i get it as group after configured it on the backend?

Answer (score 2):

You need add new field to the `sys_file_reference` TCA:

**Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_reference.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'sys_file_reference',
    [
        'tx_myext_description' => [
            'label' => 'My field description',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => '80',
                'rows' => '15',
                'enableRichtext' => true,
                'richtextConfiguration' => 'default'
            ]
        ],
    ]
);
```

**ext_tables.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE sys_file_reference (
  tx_myext_description mediumtext,
);
```

Remember to add new field into database (using database compare tool in install tool).

Then use it in TCA of your new slider:

**Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php**

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['my_slider'] = [
    'showitem' => '
    --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.headers;headers,bodytext,assets;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.media,
   ',
    'columnsOverrides' => [
        'bodytext' => [
            'config' => [
                'enableRichtext' => true,
                'richtextConfiguration' => 'default'
            ]
        ],
        'assets' => [
            'config' => [
                'overrideChildTca' => [
                    'types' => [
                        0 => ['showitem' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['types'][0]['showitem'].',tx_myext_description'],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                            'showitem' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['types'][\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT]['showitem'].',tx_myext_description'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                            'showitem' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['types'][\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE]['showitem'].',tx_myext_description'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                            'showitem' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['types'][\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO]['showitem'].',tx_myext_description'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                            'showitem' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['types'][\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO]['showitem'].',tx_myext_description'
                        ],
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                            'showitem' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['types'][\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION]['showitem'].',tx_myext_description'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

And then your Fluid template may look like that:

**Slider.html**

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<h1>{data.header}</h1>
<p>{data.bodytext}</p>
<f:for each="{images}" as="image">
    <f:image image="{image}" alt="{file.properties.alt}" cropVariant="desktop"/>
    {image.properties.tx_myext_description -> f:format.html()}
</f:for>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you enable the reach editor on the caption of the image. It is a neat idea, but i would like to have the images and the text editor separated when i create the multiple records. You get +1 from me cause it is technically a solution. Just not the one i am looking for. :)

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas just adjusted the code in the post above. Now it is separated from image - description works as before, while your RTE content will be kept in new field `tx_myext_description`.

Comment: @mrf This is just what I needed thanks. The new field seems to replace the Image Manipulation part, can this be avoided? And how would I remove the metadata fields?

Comment: @mrf Nevermind, I realised I just use `['showitem'] = ` instead of `['showitem'].`